# build json response in python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to capture exceptions into one json object and print the output

```
import json, sys, traceback
import requests
output = {}
try:
    r = requests.get('http://wwww.google.com/nothere')
    r.raise_for_status()
    print(r)

except requests.exceptions.Timeout as et:
    output['status_code']='TIMEOUT'
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message']= json.dumps(et)
    #print("Timeout: ",et)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as eh:
    output['status_code']='HTTPError'
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message'] = json.dumps(eh)
    #print("HTTPError: ",eh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    output['status_code']='ConnectTimeout'
    output['status']='failed'
    errorMessage = errc
    print("Message: ",errorMessage)
    output['message'] = errorMessage
    #print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    output['status_code']='GENErr'
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message'] = json.dumps(err)
print (json.dumps(output))
```

Output:

```
Message: HTTPConnectionPool(host='wwww.google.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /nothere (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001B3A54384C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ServiceNow\Teradatacsdev\agent\scripts\TDCloudNSPythonLibrary\helloworld.py", line 30, in <module>
    print (json.dumps(output))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type ConnectionError is not JSON serializable
```

Expected output:

```
{"status_code": "ConnectTimeout", "status": "failed", "message":"HTTPConnectionPool(host='wwww.google.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /nothere (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001C5F15684C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))"}
```

I am trying to capture entire exception message in output['message'] json object. Any idea if I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `err` is the exception object itself, which is not JSON serializable, so you cannot pass it in `json.dumps()`. You need to convert it to a str by doing `json.dumps(str(err))`

Answer (score 0):

```
import json, sys, traceback
import requests
output = {}
try:
    r = requests.get('http://wwww.google.com/nothere')
    r.raise_for_status()
    print(r)

except requests.exceptions.Timeout as et:
    output['status_code']='TIMEOUT'
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message']= json.dumps(str(et))
    #print("Timeout: ",et)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as eh:
    output['status_code']='HTTPError'
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message'] = json.dumps(str(eh))
    #print("HTTPError: ",eh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    output['status_code']='ConnectTimeout'
    output['status']='failed'
    errorMessage = errc
    print("Message: ",errorMessage)
    output['message'] = str(errorMessage)
    #print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    output['status_code']='GENErr'
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message'] = json.dumps(str(err))
print (json.dumps(output))
```